# My phone doesn't boot at all after restarting bootloader

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, unbricking, bootloader

My phone is Huawei Y3II.

Now, my phone is not starting, no matter how I press the power button.

I have tried [Smart Phone Flash Tool](https://spflashtool.com/), but it failed and it got an error 2004 - 6045.  Now, it does nothing when I click on "Download".

I have restarted the bootloader with [ROM Toolbox Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox)

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it by flashing every partition alone while the battery is off the phone .. and then hard rest ....... fuuuucccckkkk yeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhh